# Using views to create comic reader

Tags: views, paging, navigation

I'm trying to create a comic reader like a flip book. I think the views module can do this but I don't know how to do it.
I plan to structure like this:

```
Terms (Series)
     - Sub Term (Chapters)
           - Nodes using image field (Pictures)
```

What I want to do is I want make a views in the subterms to show only one node at a time but the node contains the image that is linked to the next node in sequence order. So how can I do this? I only want the nodes from the subterm to show up

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of moving parts here. I'm going to make some assumptions. First, you have nodes. Each node has 1 image on it (through a file / image field).

You then want to display the nodes in some sequence order (maybe through a slideshow or something).

Each time you look at the view, you should only look at one "flip book" at a time.

For this you need to use a Views "Contextual Filter" (or "argument" in the older language). You would build your page view to pull in all the images of all the nodes. You would probably set your views to display as a views_slideshow or something.

The first "contextual filter" your view will have is the term (I'm assuming from taxonomy) that you want to build the flip book from. So, you might go and view yoursite.com/flipbook/37 (where 37 is the term id that all the image nodes are tagged with for this book).